# Gatsby Query type not showing in graphiQl

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I was creating a gatsby plugin. On develop I don't get any errors or warning but I can't see my query in graphiql (or at http://localhost:8000/___graphql)

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Gatsby Default Starter`,
    description: `Kick off your next, great Gatsby project with this default starter. This barebones starter ships with the main Gatsby configuration files you might need.`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-custom',
      options: {
        workspaceId: 'spaceyfi-dummy',
        schemaId: 'custom-development'
      }
    },
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
    // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ],
}
```

Where this is my plugin folder structure in root

Inside the folder, `index.js` is empty file 
[image]

and getsby-node.js looks something like this

```
 const selfSdk = require('selfSdk')

 function createNodeContent (data, id, type) {
  const nodeId = createNodeId(id)
  const nodeContent = JSON.stringify(data)
  const contentDigest = createContentDigest(data)
  const nodeMeta = {
    id: nodeId,
    parent: null,
    children: [],
    internal: {
      type: type, // used to generate the resulting GraphQL query name
      content: nodeContent,
      contentDigest
    }
  }
  const node = Object.assign({}, data, nodeMeta)
  return node
}

exports.sourceNodes = async ({ actions, createNodeId, createContentDigest }, {
  workspaceId, 
  schemaId
}) => {
  const { createNode, setPluginStatus } = actions
  const workspace = selfSdk.getWorkspace(workspaceId)
  console.log(workspaceId, schemaId)
  // If there is schemaId but we don't have itemId, load all posts 
  try {
      const itemsList = await workspace.read(schemaId)
      const type = `getPosts`
      itemsList.forEach(({data, id}) => {
        createNode(createNodeContent(data, id, type))
      })


} catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error Fetching data`)
    console.error(error)
  }
  setPluginStatus({
    status: {
      lastFetched: Date.now()
    }
  }) 
}
```

This my grphiql

[image]

Comment: Try debugging the value of `itemsList`. Also `createNode()` returns a Promise.

Comment: @Z.Zlatev Unable to comprehend your comment sorry.

Comment: are you running `src` through babel or something similar? otherwise, gatsby-node.js has to be in the root directory, i.e next to index.js IIRC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gatsby is going to look for a `gatsby-node.js` in the root of your plugin folder.

```
plugins/
– your-plugin/
-- gatsby-node.js
-- package.json
```

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/files-gatsby-looks-for-in-a-plugin/

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-a-source-plugin/#what-does-the-code-look-like

This is why its not showing up in your GraphiQL. There is no node to be generated from your plugin, since you have a blank `index.js` so it seems like an module that doesn't export anything.